# PDO lastInsertId() returns 0

Tags: php, pdo

I've been looking, at other questions asking the same, and can't figure out why my query won't act like it should.

My query:

```
$stmt = db()->prepare("INSERT INTO conversations (user1, user2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['userId'], $user));
echo db()->lastInsertId();
```

When I do this the lastInsertId(); keeps returning 0.

My db() function:

```
function db()
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=message_board';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root';

    try {
        $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        // exceptions handles here
    }
    return $db;
}
```

Comment: You are making a new `PDO` object every time you call `db()`. Just check if its already exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function db()
{
    static $db;

    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=message_board';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'root';

    if (!$db) {
       $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    }
    return $db;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, of course. How simple things can be sometimes. Thanks for your time :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new db connection every line.

Try:

```
$db = db();
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO conversations (user1, user2) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['userId'], $user));
echo $db->lastInsertId();
```