# PDO LastInsertId returning nothing

Tags: pdo, postgresql-9.2, lastinsertid

For some reason I cannot get the `LastInsertId` from my `PDO` insert. I am receiving nothing back, if I place it inside the execute I get -1 because the insert query hasn't run. However when just after the execute to grab the last ID inserted nothing is returned.

```
php 5.1.6
PECL pdo = 0.1.0
```

I have looked at following questions and many other stack exchange questions.

1. [lastInsertId does not work in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492566/lastinsertid-does-not-work-in-postgresql)
2. [PDO lastInsertId() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055671/pdo-lastinsertid-returns-0)
3. [PDO lastInsertId issues, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675766/pdo-lastinsertid-issues-php?rq=1)

However the difference is nothing is returned compared to 0. No errors are recorded either. See the code below.

**Connection**

```php
try {
  $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost port= dbname=", "", "");
  echo "PDO connection object created";
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

**insert / return the last id**

```php
$stmt = $conn ->prepare("INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  username, additionalvolunteers) VALUES(?,?,?)"); 
$stmt->bindParam(1,$site_id);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$username1);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$additionalvolunteers);
$site_id = $_POST['site_id'];   
$username1 = $user->name;
$additionalvolunteers = $_POST['additionalvolunteers'];
$stmt ->execute();
$newsheetID = $conn->lastInsertId('sheet_id');
echo $newsheetID . "last id";
```

Comment: Do you have the row actually inserted?

Comment: Hi yes, the row inserts currently at row 23 but sheet_id = 115 @YourCommonSense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get last insert id after a prepared insert with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057954/get-last-insert-id-after-a-prepared-insert-with-pdo)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using

```
$newsheetID = $conn->lastInsertId('sheet_id_**seq**');
```

Just add `_seq` after id.

Answer (score 0):

Assumming sheet_id type is [**SERIAL**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype.html) you can use [`LASTVAL()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-sequence.html)

TRY (Not tested as I dont have postgresql)

```
$newsheetID = $conn->query("SELECT LASTVAL()");
echo $newsheetID . "last id";
```

Answer (score 0):

I use postgresql in C# with the "RETURNING rowkey" and its has always worked for me.
I also use pdo/php in a lot of applications.
However i dont have a postgres database open to the server right now for testing.
This could should work but it is not tested.

```
$site_id = $_POST['site_id'];   
$username1 = $user->name;
$additionalvolunteers = $_POST['additionalvolunteers'];

$stmt = $conn ->prepare("INSERT INTO sheet_tbl (site_id,  username, additionalvolunteers) VALUES(:site_id, :username1, :additionalvolunteers) RETURNING row_id"); 

$success = $stmt->execute([
    'site_id' => $site_id,
    'username1' => $username1,
    'additionalvolunteers' =>  $additionalvolunteers
]);
// unsure about this
$newsheetID =  $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $newsheetID . " last id";
```